# Is there a name for a substance that is a gas at room temperature?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, ideal-gas, condensation

Is there a name for a substance that is a gas at room temperature, such as Hydrogen, Helium, Neon, Argon, Krypton, Xenon, Chlorine, Fluorine, Bromine, Nitrogen, and Oxygen.

I am writing a paper where I refer to:  a “room temperature gas” that has been cooled to a liquid or solid state.  The word that I am looking for should replace “room temperature gas”

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already seen the term "gas" being defined as a substance that is in vapor state in room temperature...

Comment: gas a state of matter, it can exist at any temperature.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I'm just saying that I have seen that definition in some engineering books (probably transport-related).

Comment: Gas is sometimes interpreted that way as in the oxymoronic LPG.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquefied_petroleum_gas

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there isn't a specific term for these types of gasses.

In your question you name "substance" while you list elements. Many different molecules are gaseous at room temperature; however, only a few of the elements are. I'll look at both. 
They come from different parts of the periodic table but do have a couple of features in common:

Elements that are gases at room temperature are all nonmetals 
Molecules that are gases at room temperature all have covalent bonds that contain two or more nonmetals.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I am writing a paper where I refer to:  a “room temperature gas” that has been cooled to a liquid or solid state.  The word that I am looking for should replace “room temperature gas”

Comment: Depending on context you could user a couple of different terms if you just want to avoid repeating 'room temperature gas' over and over. Maybe just start off by stating that the set of gases you are discussing are those that are gaseous at STP and then just refer to them as gases afterwards.

Comment: "Two or more nonmetals"?  Do you mean two distinct nonmetals?  How about tungsten hexafluoride?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten_hexafluoride

Answer (score -1):

Substances that evaporate at room temperature could be described as volatile.

Comment: Nice. Could you please add a reference? (e.g., a definition of volatile from a well-known and respectable source). Thanks!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform If somebody asked me to add a reference for the definition for *a common English word* (except on the English Learners forum of course) I would probably remember not to bother answering any of their questions in future. Just sayin' ;)